# Find my bug. C++ programming exercise

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef _SOLDIER_H_
#define _SOLDIER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Soldier {
    // your code here
    private:
           stack<int> list;
    public:
           Soldier(int num);
           bool check(vector<int> arrange);               
};

#endif
```

Error is at the above Soldier.h, at bool check(vector arrange); 
15 C:\Users\king boon\Desktop\CS1020E\lab4\lab4\ex1\skeleton\Soldier.h expected `;' before '(' token

```
#include "Soldier.h"

// your code here
Soldier::Soldier(int num) {
                     int i;
                     for (i=1; i<=num; i++) {
                         list.push(i);
                         }
                     };

bool Soldier::check(vector<int> arrange) {



     return true;
     };
```

Been trying for hours, at my wits end. Thanks.

Comment: Using `list` as a variable name is very confusing since there is `<list>` header in STL

Comment: I consider both using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) and having a using directive in a header to be bugs.

Answer (score 3):

vector isn't declared:

```
#include <vector>
```